# TypeScript require with type checking

Tags: typescript, require

I am using TypeScript v1.4.1 and would like to require an external module (in this case "chai") and have it be type checked.

However, I am running into some sort of naming conflict with this code:

```
/// <reference path="../typings/node/node.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="../typings/chai/chai.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="../typings/mocha/mocha.d.ts" />

var chai = require("chai");

var expect = chai.expect;
var assert = chai.assert;

describe("TEST", () =>
{
   it("true should be true", (done)=>
   {
      expect(true).to.be.true;
      done();
   });
});
```

With this definition file:

```
declare module chai {
   ...
}
declare module "chai" {
   export = chai;
}
```

Compiling gives these errors:

```
test/test.ts(5,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'chai'.
typings/chai/chai.d.ts(6,16): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'chai'.
```

It seems my only option is rename my `chai` variable name in test.ts.  That seems clunky AND won't type check the use of the renamed `chai` variable.

Any advice?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use the [`import`](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Handbook#modules-going-external) keyword with `require` instead of `var`

```
import chai = require('chai');
```

And compile with `--module commonjs` if you're not already

Or, if for some reason you don't want the test code to be an external module, adding a type annotation will preserve type checking.

```
var c: typeof chai = require("chai");
```

Comment: If I do that I can't use `--out` because this file becomes an external module according to TypeScript: a top level import or export statement makes the file an external module.

Comment: I updated my answer to include another option, though you'll still have to rename the variable. It might be helpful for you to include some more info about how you're bundling the code and running the tests because it's not clear to me why you would want to use `--out`.

Comment: Thank you.  We found that `:typeof` option and it works.  Let me pick your brain a little though...

It is our understanding that if we do no use the `--out` compile flag, then all our files will be compiled as external modules.  Is that true?

Comment: Yes that's true. If you're runtime (e.g. node, requirejs) includes a module loader, that seems like the desired behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Since **TypeScript 3.9 Beta** was released it's possible to use `require` with typing

Example:

```
const {someValue} = require('fs')
```

"TypeScript now automatically detects the types of imports you’re using to keep your file’s style clean and consistent."

ref. https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-3-9-beta/

Comment: What does it mean, to "to keep your file’s style clean and consistent"? I'm not sure if it has actually started to type-check `require`, because nothing changed for me after updating to 3.9.9.