# Node.js with typescript require and .d.ts files

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, q

I want to create an server side script, for this I require "Q",
so I include the q.d.ts file.
And I use this to import q:

```
var Q = require("q");
```

Now I recive this error: Duplicate identifier 'Q'

Does somebody know how to solve this name conflict?

The complete startup script:+

```
    ///<reference path="Scripts/typings/q/Q.d.ts" />
///<reference path="Server.ts" />
///<reference path="Services/DatabaseProvider.ts" />
///<reference path="Response/Response.ts" />
///<reference path="Response/DataResponse.ts" />


var Q = require("q");
var di = require("ng-di");
var app = di.module("App", []);
app.service("server", Server);
app.service("$databaseProvider", DatabaseProvider);
app.run((server: Server) => {
    server.run();
});

di.injector(["App"]);
```

Comment: Missing information. Where is this q file coming from?

Comment: https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/q/Q.d.ts

Comment: Can you include some more code? You probably referenced it twice...

Comment: Do you referencing q on the other files too?

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28547970/typescript-require-with-type-checking ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Duplicate identifier 'Q'

In the absence of an `import` or an `export` statement at the root of your file: Your file as well as any other such file passed to the TypeScript compiler is considered a part of the *global namespace*. So the variable `Q` is conflicting with the one declared in `q.d.ts`.

**Fix**

`import` Q, don't just `require` it :

```
import Q = require("q");
```

More about External modules : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KDrWLMUY0R0