# Using .d.ts. files for JS intended for Node and a Web-Worker

Tags: node.js, typescript, require, web-worker

I'm using the library `Q` in a script that I'd like to run in a web-worker and in  Node. If I reference [`q.d.ts`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/q/Q.d.ts) like so:

```
/// <reference path="../typings/q/Q.d.ts" />

if(importScripts != undefined &&  WorkerGlobalScope == undefined 
        && typeof module !== 'undefined' && module.exports){

    // We're in a Node (child) process
    var Q = require("q")
}else{
    // We're in a web-worker
    importScripts('q');
}
```

I get the following error, which is nicely explained in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29059084/1519199):

```
error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'Q'.
```

but if I substitute `var Q = require("q")` with `import Q = require("q")`, I get this error, because the import statement is nested within the `if` clause and not at the top level of the script:

```
An import declaration can only be used in a namespace or module.
```

Is there a way to require `Q` in so that it works with both node's `require()` and web-worker's `importScripts()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to require Q in so that it works with both node's require() and web-worker's importScripts()?

You need to import just the *type* of `Q` and then load the `q` lazily *if needed*. So:

```
import _Q = require('q');
if(importScripts != undefined &&  WorkerGlobalScope == undefined 
        && typeof module !== 'undefined' && module.exports){

    // we're in a Node (child) process
    var Q:typeof _Q = require("q")
}else{

    importScripts('q');
}
```

## More

This is covered in the lazy loading section here : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/project/external-modules.html

Comment: This works great when a `.d.ts` file declares a module, but for those that don't, such as [`require.d.ts`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/q/Q.d.ts) the `import _r = require('requirejs')` results in this error: `Cannot find module 'requirejs'.`

Comment: I have [another related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38016793) that would be great if you could take a look at.  Thanks!