# Unable to use requireJS and Node's Require in the same TypeScript project

Tags: node.js, typescript, requirejs

I have a typescript project targeted at both Node and the browser.  I'm using Node's `require()` in some scripts and requireJS's `require()` in others. My project directory looks like this:

```
myProject
  \-- a.ts 
  \-- b.ts
  \-- node.d.ts
  \-- require.d.ts
```

where `a.ts` contains:

```
/// <reference path="./node.d.ts" />
var cp = require('child-process');
var a = 'hello world'
export = a
```

and `b.ts` contains:

```
/// <reference path="./require.d.ts" />
require('hello',function(x){console.log('world')});
var b = 'hello world'
export = b
```

and where `require.d.ts` and `node.d.ts` are obtained from [DefinitlyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped).

When I compile my project, I get these errors:

```
b.ts(2,1): error TS2346: Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.
require.d.ts(396,13): error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'require' must be of type 'NodeRequire', but here has type 'Require'.
```

I use this idiom to determine which modules to load, so I'm not loading a node module in the browser or vice versa.

```
if(typeof module !== 'undefined' && module.exports){

    // We're in a Node process

}else{

    // We're in an AMD module in the browser:

}
```

Is there a way to use both of these `.d.ts` files in the same project. It seems using them in separate modules is not enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way to use both of these .d.ts files in the same project

I highly recommend going with `commonjs` everywhere. That is what the React community has spearheaded and it's a much simpler workflow. Just use CommonJS + webpack (to get lazy `require.ensure` from [here](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-loader#loading-other-resources-and-code-splitting)).

There's also a quickstart for [TypeScript in the browser environment](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/quick/browser.html).

Comment: No worries. Fwiw I have this workflow I use to develop https://github.com/alm-tools/alm Super easy to experiment with new tech. However I don't have the need for a lazy `require.ensure` :)

Answer (score 0):

In the end what I needed was the ability to `require()` JS content that is compiled on the fly by the server -- [which doesn't seem to work with web-pack](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/118#issuecomment-40000400).

To suppress the errors from the typescript compiler in the original question, I commented out this line from `require.d.ts` (the RequireJS declaration file):

```
declare var require: Require;
```

and I used the `{foo:bar}['f'+'oo']` trick to get `tsc` to 'forget' the type of the ambient `require` variable when assigning it to the typed `requirejs` variable, like so:

```
var requirejs:Require; // requirejs
if(typeof module !== 'undefined' && module.exports){
    // We're in a Node process
    requirejs = require('requirejs');
}else{
    // We're in an AMD module in the browser:
    requirejs = {require:require}['req'+'ire'];
}
// use requirejs for dynamic require statements
requirejs(gather_requirements(),do_things);
```