# How can I use the typescript definitions for both Gulp and RequireJS in the same project?

Tags: visual-studio, typescript, gulp, asp.net-core, requirejs

I have a Visual Studio 2015 ASP.Net Core project which uses Gulp and RequireJS. Gulp is used at compile-time, and RequireJS is used at run-time.

The typescript definitions for Gulp include the definitions  for node, and this causes a definition collision with RequireJS:

`TS2403 Build:Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'require' must be of type 'NodeRequire', but here has type 'Require'.`

Is there a way to work around this?

#### Manually Editing the Definitions

I don't want to manually edit the definition files as that would create maintenance problems compared to just getting them directly from NPM.

Also it wouldn't fully solve the problem as `require` would have the wrong type in one of the situations depending on which I commented out.

#### Relevant SO Questions

I found this question: [Unable to use requireJS and Node's Require in the same TypeScript project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38016793/unable-to-use-requirejs-and-nodes-require-in-the-same-typescript-project).

It has an answer suggesting using CommonJS everywhere, but as I don't own the Gulp or RequireJS typings I can't change that.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully you're using two tsconfig.jsons, one for compile-time concerns and one for run-time concerns. With two configs you can explicitly choose which types to apply to each target with the `types` compiler option.

Comment: How do you get Visual Studio to honour the two different tsconfig files?

Comment: Unfortunately they have be in separate directories and explicitly named `tsconfig.json`. I used to have two build targets, one in directory `a` and one in directory `b`, but my tsconfigs.jsons were sibling to these directories: `tsconfig-a.json` and `tsconfig-b.json`. I had to rename both and move them into directories `a` and `b` respectively.