# Duplicate identifier error when referencing a node library using typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, hapi.js

I'm new to typescript and trying to start a hapi.js project but I'm getting an error when trying require('boom') in my code

`Duplicate identifier 'Boom'`

```
/// <reference path="../typings/tsd.d.ts" />

var config = require('../config'),
    User = require('../models/user'),
    Boom = require('boom'),
    joi = require('joi');
```

my tsd.json

```
{
  "version": "v4",
  "repo": "borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped",
  "ref": "master",
  "path": "typings",
  "bundle": "typings/tsd.d.ts",
  "installed": {
    "node/node.d.ts": {
      "commit": "846a250e0a6f5e6adf6347ee4ca442a9d1abd8fc"
    },
    "hapi/hapi.d.ts": {
      "commit": "846a250e0a6f5e6adf6347ee4ca442a9d1abd8fc"
    },
    "bluebird/bluebird.d.ts": {
      "commit": "846a250e0a6f5e6adf6347ee4ca442a9d1abd8fc"
    },
    "boom/boom.d.ts": {
      "commit": "846a250e0a6f5e6adf6347ee4ca442a9d1abd8fc"
    },
    "pg/pg.d.ts": {
      "commit": "846a250e0a6f5e6adf6347ee4ca442a9d1abd8fc"
    }
  }
```

I've added both boom and hapi to my tsd - if hapi references boom as well does that cause some sort of circular error?

How should I be referencing these libraries in typescript?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28547970/typescript-require-with-type-checking/28548551

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't put a global `import` or `export` in your file then as far as TypeScript is concerned you file is a part of a *global* namespace and therefore you are getting a name collision on `Boom`. Fix: use `import/require` instead of `var/require`.

```
import Boom = require('boom');
```

To learn more : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KDrWLMUY0R0&hd=1