# Visual Studio typescript project with a node package raises duplicate identifier errors

Tags: npm, typescript, visual-studio-2015, angular

I've added Angular 2 to a Visual Studio Typescript project using NPM.  Because of its dependency management, there are multiple copies of certain dependencies, like "es6-shim.d.ts".  This results in the build failing because of multiple "duplicate identifier"s.  What is the simplest way for me to resolve this problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Duplicate identifier error when referencing a node library using typescript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30201985/duplicate-identifier-error-when-referencing-a-node-library-using-typescript)